# Optimization algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, genetic

I want to calculate maximum of the function CROSS-IN-TRAY which is 
shown here:

[image: formula for cross in tray]

So I have made this function in Matlab:

```
function f = CrossInTray2(x)
%the CrossInTray2 objective function
%
f = 0.0001 *(( abs(sin(x(:,1)).* sin(x(:,2)).*exp(abs(100 - sqrt(x(:,1).^2 + x(:,2).^2)/3.14159 ))      )+1 ).^0.1);
end
```

I multiplied the whole formula by (-1) so the function is inverted so when I will be looking for the minimum of the inverted formula it will be actually the maximum of original one.

Then when I go to optimization tools and select the GA algorithm and define lower and upper bounds as -3 and 3 it shows me the result after about 60 iterations which is about 0.13 and the final point is something like [0, 9.34].
And how is this possible that the final point is not in the range defined by the bounds? And what is the actual maximum of this function?

Comment: Where is the code you wrote that uses the Optimization Toolbox to find the minimum of this function? It is missing and that is at the core of what is wrong. Without it, we don't know why you are getting the errors you claim to be having.

Comment: i didn't write any code. I typed optimtool in the command window and then selected ga as the solver, defined lower and upper bounds as i said before and so on

Comment: `Note:   ga does not enforce bounds to be satisfied when the PopulationType option is 'bitString' or 'custom'.`  http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html

Answer (score 1):

The maximum is (0,0) (actually, when *either* input is 0, and periodically at multiples of pi).  After you negate, you're looking for a minimum of a positive quantity.  Just looking at the outer absolute value, it obviously can't get lower than 0.  That trivially occurs when either value of `sin(x)` is 0.
Plugging in, you have `f_min = f(0,0) = .0001(0 + 1)^0.1 = 1e-4`

This expression is trivial to evaluate and plot over a 2d grid.  Do that until you figure out what you're looking at, and what the approximate answer should be, and only then invoke an actual optimizer.  GA does not sound like a good candidate for a relatively smooth expression like this.  The reason you're getting strange answers is the fact that only one of the input parameters has to be 0.  Once the optimizer finds one of those, the other input could be anything.